# How to create Editioning View in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert a ddl for a oracle view to snowflake view. But in Oracle ddl the view created is of FORCE EDITIONING type. But these keywords are not supported by snowflake. Can anyone share the ideas to replicate the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11g Release 2 introduced "Editions" so people could upgrade an application's database objects while the application is in use, and then essentially flip a switch after all modifications were complete and users could then begin running all of their commands on the new "edition" or "release" of their objects.

Snowflake doesn't have this capability (yet), so you'll need to omit that clause from your Create View command.

Here are the docs on creating a view in Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html

I hope this helps...Rich